# Is there any way to get a three finger touch in the iPhone simulator

Tags: iphone, multi-touch

I have an app that I need to test 3 finger touches and 2 finger touches, is there a FREE application that allows me to use 3 finger instead of being limited to only using 2 fingers like in the simulator?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[iSimulate](http://www.vimov.com/isimulate/) by vimov might be close to what you are looking for.  I've sent the question of three finger touches to their support.  Unfortunately, it is not FREE ($15.99) and requires you have an iPhone or iPod Touch to use it.  You do not need to be a signed up developer though.

**UPDATE:** I got the following reply from support:

> Yes, iSimulate works with up to five
>   fingers which is the limit of iPhone
>   touch screen.

Comment: Did support provide any insight into how to perform a 3+ finger touch on iOS simulator?

Answer (score 6):

Not that I'm aware of. I think the iPhone Simulator included in the SDK is the only one that exists. You can't test a 3-fingered gesture without using the actual device.

Answer (score 0):

On MKMapView, you can simulate a three-finger pan gesture by holding `⌥ + shift` and dragging your finger up/down.

Didn't test if it works with other components of the OS.